# Simple way to check login session on all controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am storing admin login in session in login controller.
Now i want to check user login session on all other controller.
Can someone help with simplest way to do this?

Comment: add check session function in constructor .

Comment: can u share code for constructor.

Comment: Write function in helper and call that function in constructor of each controller.

Comment: The best way is, to have a basecontroller, which is included in every controller.

Answer (score 2):

i would use a hook here - because your session validation should be always the first thing before you do anything else

in your application/config/hooks.php type this

```
$hook['pre_controller'][] = array(
    "class" => "AppSessionValidator",
    "function" => "initialize",
    "filename" => "AppSessionValidator.php",
    "filepath" => "hooks"
);
```

After that create a File in application/hooks/
named AppSessionValidator.php and type this kind of code in

```
class AppSessionValidator
{

    private $ci;
    private $strRedirectUrl = "/login/";
    private $currentController;
    private $arrExludedControllers = array("login");


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->ci = &get_instance();
        $this->currentController = $this->ci->router->class;
    }

    public function initialize()
    {
        if (!$this->ci->session->userdata("is_logged_in") && !in_array($this->currentController, $this->arrExludedControllers)
        {
            redirect($this->strRedirectUrl);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to check login session on all controllers, i think the best way to go would be to use the autoload file in config.

Create a helper file `check_session.php` in application/helpers/ and add this

```
<?php
    //Get Current CI Instance
    $CI = & get_instance();
    //Use $CI instead of $this
    //Check for session details here, here's an example
    $user = $CI->session->userdata('user_id');

    //Get current controller to avoid infinite loop
    $controller = $CI->router->class;

    //Check if user session exists and you are not already on the login page
    if(empty($user) && $controller != "login" ) {
        redirect('login/', 'refresh');
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
?>
```

Now go to your autoload.php file at application/config/autoload.php and look for where your helper array is declared and add `check_session` to your helper list
`$autoload['helper'] = array();
$autoload['helper'] = array('url','utility', 'check_session');`

With that... you should be able to check sessions automatically on all controllers

Answer (score 1):

while login:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('is_logged_in',TRUE);
```

Create model:

```
  class Security_model extends CI_Model{
    public function is_logged_in(){
        if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')){
             return true;
        }
        else{
             $this->session->set_flashdata('feedback','Please login!');
             redirect('login');
       }
      }
    }
```

On your Any controller's Contructor:

```
$this->load->model('security_model');
$this->security_model->is_logged_in();
```